# Passing arguments between npm scripts

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package.json

I have two npm scripts, one of which calls the other.

```
"no-local-build": "cd ./server && if [ \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"development\" ]; then  npx ts-node src/tasks/$npm_config_task.ts $@; else node build/tasks/$npm_config_task.js $@; fi;",
"runner": "npm run no-local-build --task=<task>"
```

The idea is that `no-local-build` will check the node environment and determine whether we can run the task using `ts-node` or we need to run the compiled version. The issue is that I can't figure out how to pass the arguments from the runner script to `no-local-build` so they're not appended to the end of the script, but are appended conditionally to the `ts-node` call or the `node` call.

I've tried refactoring the npm script to it's own Bash file, which seems to do what I want but I'd prefer to have it as an npm script. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Write a shell script. Seriously, once you get beyond 2 commands in  a string it's time to write a script.

Comment: Another bonus of writing scripts instead of commands is if you have devs on your team that run Windows you can write the script in js using `child_process.exec` to run commands instead of bash/sh scripts for Windows compatibility.